# Given Position equation Solve for t

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is calculus, and here is given information:

Position of a spaceship at ***t*** hours after leaving planet is $$s(t)=.004t^3 + 400t$$
in thousands of miles.

The distance between planet and destination is ***67,000,000*** miles.  How long will it take the spaceship to reach the destination?  How fast will the spaceship be going when it gets there?

I know the answer is ***140.037 hours***, but I dont get how I can get there using strictly calculus.  I graphed it and then asked my calculator what ***t*** value gives ***67,000***.  I also know putting ***140.037*** into $$s'(t)$$ will give me the velocity.

Thank you for the help in understanding the proper way to get to this answer.

Comment: $0.004 t^3+400 t-67000=0$

Comment: This is a quite stupendous cubic equation. I request you to check the actual value of the time taken(140.037 is just an approximation) on Wolfram Alpha or the like. Fine, I'll actually post it. It's $$ 50 \biggl(\frac{^3\sqrt{603+\sqrt{555609}}}{3^{\frac{2}{3}}} \biggr) - \frac{40}{^3\sqrt{3(603+\sqrt{555609})}}$$

Comment: Thank you @abdefghijklmnopqrtxyz-stoo ,  Yours is the only one that points out it is not just a simple cubic equation.  I mentioned this is calculus in hopes that people would grasp that I am not in an algebra 1 or 2 class.  It looks like you used the cubic formula?

Comment: Yes I did. The cubic formula has a simplified version, where the coefficient of $t^2$ is absent. The formula is quite simplified in that case, yet the answers you get aren't quite nice looking, as you can see above. From no angle could you have perceived (without paramount forethought) that the answer to even a simplified cubic could be so complex.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve a cubic equation.  There is a formula for [cubic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) in the same spirit as the quadratic formula you probably know.  It is pretty messy, but will give you an exact answer.  Alternately you can search for a numeric answer using a variety of techniques.  You can just try numbers until you find one that is close.  You can use bisection, the secant method, Newton-Raphson, or a fixed point approach.  These are discussed in numerical analysis texts.

Comment: Yes it appears this may be the only way, short of a graphing calculator.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply an algebra problem. We have the formula for distance covered in a certain time $t$, as well as the distance to be covered total - We just need to equate these. Therefore
$$67000000=.004t^3+400t$$
Form here you have a cubic... solve any way you like.

Comment: I noted in my problem that it is actually 67000 = s(t)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want yo use the formulae for cubic equations, you can consider numerical methods such as Newton for axample. Starting from a "reasonable" guess $t_0$, the method will update it according to $$t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac{f(t_n)}{f'(t_n)}$$ In your case $$f(t)=\frac 4{1000} t^3+400 t-67000\qquad , \qquad f'(t)=\frac 6{500}t^2+400$$ which gives $$t_{n+1}=\frac{2 \left(t^3+8375000\right)}{3 t^2+100000}$$ Since $t>0$, $f(t)<400 t-67000$ and then $\frac{67000}{400}=167.5$ is an overestimate of the solution. I am very lazy, let me start using this value for $t_0$.

Applied, the method generates the following iterates $$t_1=141.98307$$ $$t_2=140.04778$$ $$t_3=140.03778$$  which is the solution for eight significant figures.

Just for your curiosity, we could have done the same work fatser using Halley method instead of Newton. Starting from the same initial value, the iterates would have been $$t_1=140.20652$$ $$t_2=140.03778$$